# Name of the segment connecting a point's coordinate axis projections?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, euclidean-geometry

Given any point $(x,y)$ in the real plane consider the corresponding line segment connecting $(x,0)$ with $(0,y)$. See diagram.

> Is there a name for this special segment?

(I believe that in higher dimensions this segment becomes a simplex.)

[image]

Comment: well this is a right-angled triangle :) and the length of the segment is the norm of the vector

Comment: @Surb: While both correct observations, they don't really answer the question.

Comment: @DivergentQueries that is why it is a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: I don't know if it has a name, but I would describe it as "the convex hull of projections onto the coordinate axes", and it will indeed be a simplex.

Comment: the vector $(x,y)$ reflected about either $X=x/2$ or $Y=y/2$